# Possible bug in Microsoft Edge in site navigation

Tags: bug, microsoft-edge

Upon going to any post on SO, if I try to comment on anything the cursor control seems to start from the next line.

To explain better:

[image]

The cursor as shown starts from **adding new information, edit your post...**

This is the same for both type of comment boxes:

[image]

Even if I try to navigate to the upper line it doesn't let me. Are we looking at another bug?

**EDIT** Here's a Stack Snippet without any third party libraries which produces the bug on Edge version 20.10240.16384.0 (Thanks [m0sa](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155005/m0sa))

```html
<textarea placeholder="Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." rows="3" cols="68"></textarea>
```

Comment: Interesting. Could this be related to [Cursor not shown when commenting on the answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305777/cursor-not-shown-when-commenting-on-the-answers)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I am not sure as my cursor looks fine but it is not at the right place. I have tried restarting my browser but its the same.

Comment: Stack Overflow is barely usable on Microsoft Edge right now. It will take a while for both SE and Microsoft to iron out all the issues.

Comment: @Bolt, which one do you think is the long pole? ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Do you mean which will take 6 weeks and which will take 8?

Comment: @Jon, always a pleasure to have you here :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Isn't 8 weeks a bit optimistic? I mean, one's an established, well-respected software company that takes a while to respond to user feedback, and the other is Microsoft.

Comment: I'm confused.  Is this about a bug in Edge or a bug in Stack Overflow?  (And if it's the former, is this really the best place to report it?)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Other textareas seem to work just fine in Edge. So I am guessing its a Stack issue?!

Comment: @Jeffrey Bosboom: Who knows? It will take a bit of debugging, and possibly someone familiar with Edge, to figure out.

Comment: I don't know whether this is related, but since a few weeks, entering text into facebook with IE shows similar behaviour: the cursor is put on the second line of an empty text box. Maybe a third-party library like jQuery that is used by both SO and Facebook has introduced a change that doesn' agree with IE and Edge?

Comment: @m69 See [m0sa's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155005/m0sa) [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306114/). I don't think if that's the case because the answer has plain html without any 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Reproducible in edge 20.10240.16384.0 with this simple snippet bellow (as well as on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3sn77f5w/embedded/result/)) w/o any 3rd party library:

```html
 <textarea placeholder="Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." rows="3" cols="68"></textarea>
```